# Lost admin password for geographicinfo_devel@kforge.ros.org

Tags: ros, kforge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am the administrator for the Geographic Info devel mailing list. I need to approve a message, but have forgotten the admin password. (I do know my subscription password, but that does not work for admin access.)

I can't figure out how to discover or reset this password.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31768/lost-admin-password-for-geographicinfo_devel@kforge.ros.org/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I somehow missed this post. The list password has been reset, turns out you need to ask an administrator to do that for you, and the ticket closed.

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2012-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-20**:
Thanks, Eitan. I did not know who ask about it.